# Android jetpack compose - Drawable colors

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am having the following issue. I am adding some vector drawable images in my project which is built using Jetpack compose. I am overriding the colors of the drawable by setting

```
android:fillColor="?colorPrimary"
```

But, the previous solution, even though it works on a usual Android project, when working on Jetpack compose it is not.

Of course, I have initialized a Material Theme with my colors/typo/shapes.

Any suggetions?

Best regards!

Comment: Please show a sample of how you are adding your vector image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am importing a vector drawable with the native way of adding svg images to an Android project - nothing special.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Compose. The code you added is for xml based views.

Comment: The same drawable would work great if I had a Material theme at an Android Project. It looks like that resource fails to resolve attribute colorPrimary.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into similar issues where compose doesn't play well with attributes. It prefers to access via colorResource(R.color.colorName).

What you might be looking for is either of the below implementations:

```
Icon(
 Icons.Filled, 
 "contentDescription",
 tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
)

Image(
    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.resourceName), 
    contentDescription = "contentDescription", 
    colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.myColor)
)
```

**UPDATE:**

I actually found something similar with font attributes. You might want to try something like this:

```
fun getFontFromAttribute(resId: Int, context: Context): Typeface? =
    context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.MYSTYLE, intArrayOf(resId))
        .use { array ->
            val resource = array.getResourceId(array.getIndex(0), 0)
            if (resource == 0) {
                null
            } else {
                ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, resource) ?: Typeface.SANS_SERIF
            }
        }
```